# Unable to disable button after post back asp.net

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net

I'm trying to create an web application where I have a button and if I click the button then a specified file will get downloaded and button should became disabled. Following code I use to do so

```
protected void btnDownload_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        btnDownload.Enabled = false;
        string filepath = @"D:\SomeLayout.pdf";
        string filename = Path.GetFileName(filepath);
        Stream stream = null;
        try
        { 
            stream = new FileStream(filepath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read);
            long bytesToRead = stream.Length;
            Response.ContentType = "application/octet-stream";
            Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + filename);
            while (bytesToRead > 0)
            {
                if (Response.IsClientConnected)
                {
                    byte[] buffer = new Byte[10000];
                    int length = stream.Read(buffer, 0, 10000);
                    Response.OutputStream.Write(buffer, 0, length);
                    Response.Flush();
                    bytesToRead = bytesToRead - length;
                }
                else
                {
                    bytesToRead = -1;
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
        }
        finally
        {
            if (stream != null)
            {
                stream.Close();
            }
        }
    }
```

Once I click the button the file got downloaded but the button remains enable. I tried those all downloading code calling from other method but same problem occurs. But if I remove those code for download then after click the button it becomes disable. I'm not sure why the problem is and please help me to get a solution.

The asp.net button I used

```
<asp:Button ID="btnDownload" runat="server" Text="Download" OnClick="btnDownload_Click"/>
```

Even if its possible by java script/jquery with meeting requirement please suggests me a solution.

Comment: Do you have something in your Page_Load or another function called by your Page_Load that might be re-enabling the button on post back?

Comment: @mason No I did not put any code in page load

Answer (score 0):

## This is super easy !

```
<asp:Button ID="btnDownload" runat="server" Text="Download" OnClick="btnDownload_Click" OnClientClick="$(this).attr('disabled','disabled');return true;"/>
```

Just added `OnClientClick="$(this).attr('disabled','disabled');return true;"`

The above should work.

## What it does ?

When the user clicks the button, JavaScript will disable the button on the client side, and return true which allows the postback to occur and run the event handler specified for OnClick (btnDownload_Click).

Comment: While I agree that disabling it with JavaScript should work in most cases, it's important for the OP to understand the ASP.NET Page Life Cycle, which likely provides the explanation for why his code isn't working as expected. Disabling it on the client side isn't going to do any good if his postback re-enables the button.

Comment: @mason Agree with you. I tried something simile to above javascript, the button remains enable.

Answer (score 0):

To me if you are using `Webform` and didn't disable the `Viewstate`, the page use the data contained it to rehydrate the controls on the page so if you disabled a button it should stay disabled after postback.